# Convert a date/time from UTC to session time zone

Tags: sql, oracle

My program receives timestamps in UTC, e.g. `Tue, 31 May 2016 11:43:47 UTC`. How do I convert them to a timestamp in the session's current timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert the string to a timestamp with timezone (use the correct function). To show the result in your local (session) time zone, use the "AT LOCAL" clause.

```
select to_timestamp_tz('Tue, 31 May 2016 19:43:47 UTC', 
                                'Dy, dd Mon yyyy hh24:mi:ss tzr') at local from dual;
```

Result (using my front-end settings for displaying timestamp with timezone - yours may be different):

```
31-MAY-16 02.43.47.000000000 PM AMERICA/CHICAGO
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this much simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`tz_offset`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions238.htm#SQLRF06152) function to get the timezone offset for the [session's timezone](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions176.htm#SQLRF06105), then use the [`from_tz`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions077.htm#SQLRF00644) function to convert the string to a `timestamp with time zone`, and use [`at time zone`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions007.htm#SQLRF00401) to change it to use the session's timezone.

```
select from_tz(to_timestamp('Tue, 31 May 2016 11:43:47 UTC'
                           ,'Dy, dd Mon yyyy hh24:mi:ss "UTC"')
              , 'UTC')
       at time zone tz_offset(sessiontimezone)
      ,sessiontimezone
from   dual;

31/05/2016 19:43:47.000000000 +08:00    Australia/Perth
```

Comment: Why so complicated? Besides, hard-coding "UTC" in the format model is a terrible practice (I am surprised, given your reputation) - how will this work if the input is from another timezone region? The downvote is for this bad coding practice, not for the complicated solution. You should use the proper function, for timestamp with timezone.

Comment: Wait - did you ask and answer the question yourself? Seriously?

Comment: @mathguy, it's common practice to document something you find on SO by asking/answering your own question. It gives others the opportunity to give other options, and/or criticize (as you have done) :)

Comment: Hardcoding a string in a date/time format string is useful for ignoring a part of the incoming string, when you know *for certain* that it will always be there (as I do).

Comment: the documentation is (or should be) an addition to the original post, not an Answer. All those benefits remain the same.

Comment: This was *an answer* -it works correctly. It just wasn't the *best* answer.